# Adding ggplot object ontop of another ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a basketball court in ggplot using geom_segments:

```
court <- ggplot(data = data.frame(c(0, 0)), xlim=c(0,50), ylim=c(0,50)) +
    
    #NBA Court Boundaries
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = 0, yend = 47)) +   #Left
    geom_segment(aes(x = 50, y =47, xend = 50, yend = 0)) +  #Right
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 47, xend = 50, yend = 47)) + #Top/Half-court line
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = 50, yend = 0), color = 'black') +   #Bottom
    
    #Free-throw
        #Line
    geom_segment(aes(x = 19, y = 19, xend = 31, yend = 19)) +
        #Top circle
    geom_curve(aes(x = 19, y = 19, xend = 31, yend = 19), curvature = -1,
               lineend = 'round', color = 'black') +
        #Bottom circle  
    geom_curve(aes(x = 19, y = 19, xend = 31, yend = 19), curvature = 1,
               linetype = 2, lineend = 'round') +
    
    #Key
    geom_segment(aes(x = 17, y = 19, xend = 33, yend = 19)) + #Top
    geom_segment(aes(x = 17, y = 0, xend = 17, yend = 19)) +  #Left
    geom_segment(aes(x = 33, y = 0, xend = 33, yend = 19)) +  #Right
    
    #3-point Line
    geom_segment(aes(x = 3, y = 0, xend = 3, yend = 14)) +   #Left
    geom_segment(aes(x = 47, y = 0, xend = 47, yend = 14)) + #Right
    geom_curve(aes(x = 3, y = 14, xend = 47, yend = 14), curvature = -.75,
               angle = 90) + #Curve
    
    #Backboard
    geom_segment(aes(x = 22, y = 4, xend = 28, yend = 4)) +
    
    #Themes
    coord_fixed() +
```

This  code gives me an output of a court that looks like so:
[image]

I've managed to add this to my basketball shot data, but, am having trouble with the layering. If I add the court before my ggplot heatmap data, the heatmap will cover the court unless I use alpha, but that then makes the court quite hard to see:

```
heatmapAdjusted3 <- court +
    stat_density2d(subset(nbaJumpAnd3ptNoise, shotType == '3pt'), 
                   mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, fill = stat(density / max(density))), 
                   geom = 'raster',
                   interpolate = TRUE,
                   n = 200,
                   #alpha = 0.9,
                   contour = FALSE) +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 'inferno', alpha = 0.9) +
    xlab('x (ft)') +
    ylab('y (ft)') +
    scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 3.5) +
    theme(legend.position = 'none') +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black')) +
    coord_equal()
```

[image]

Which I think looks okay, but I would really like to find a way to layer the court on top of the given data instead to make the court lines a lot clearer. I have attempted making them white, but same issue as alpha just plays with the opacity.
When trying to add the court object anywhere else in the code, it will seperate the two plots side by side.

Would love anyones input if they have any ideas at all.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried changing the color of the "geom_segments" to a lighter color to provide better contrast?

Comment: I have, unfortunately doesn't help at all essentially. I believe this is because the alpha is applying to the court object as well as the heatmap

Comment: Why not simply draw your court in "white" or a lighter color. I would guess that's what Dave2e meant. Not fiddling around with opacity. BTW: Instead of using geom_curve have a look at the `ggforce` package which offers some options to draw (half-)circles using geom_arc.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(nbaJump3ptNoise)`? So we can help you better.